# Is it true that Javascript, before ECMA-262 or ECMA 5.1, doesn't have pseudo-classical inheritance or prototypal inheritance support?

Tags: javascript

The reason is that, although we can use pseudo classical inheritance in Javascript, we actually have to implement our own `extend` or `inherit`.

What about the prototypal inheritance -- I think it does have the feature that if `foo.bar` is used, if `bar` is not a property of `foo`, the interpreter or the compiled code (such as if using Google V8) will go up the prototype chain, but there is no built in method to make object `b`'s hidden prototype property point to `a` as a prototypal chain.  We have to add it by defining a `clone()` function or `Object.create()`.  What's more, I think I see in the pure prototypal inheritance code that there is no constructor whatsoever.  So it looks like in prototypal code, there is no constructor (constructor functions).  But if we use prototypal inheritance, we actually have to implement `clone()` using a constructor -- which is more like the pseudo classical inheritance side.

So it does seem that the original Javascript is actually neither Pseudo-classical nor Prototypal inheritance?  I read that it needed to be out on the market within 10 days, or else something worse would have come out to the market, according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich).  But I also wonder somewhat, why the 1 year or 2 years after Javascript came out in 1995, at least the Netscape version of Javascript didn't add an `extend` and `Object.create()` method already?

This question aims to understand and clarify some concepts in the pseudo-classical and prototypal part of Javascript.  And is it true -- the original Javascript does not by itself have pseudo-classical or prototypal inheritance support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial goal was to ape C-like languages, to make JS look familiar enough to speed up adoption.

Nobody was using JS in any way nearly advanced enough, in 1997 to even bother considering to look at prototypes.

People were still making objects like:

```
var car = new Object();
car.doors = 4;
car.wheels = 4;
car.position = new Object();
car.position.x = 230;
car.position.y = 400;
```

Even better were people who were using arrays to make those objects.

```
var car = new Array();
car["doors"] = 4;
car["wheels"] = 4;
car["position"] = new Array();
car["position"]["x"] = 230;
car["position"]["y"] = 400;
```

That's what A ***LOT*** of JS looked like in those days.

And to be honest, there's still a lot of it that does look like that, because people do still come in from Java or C# or C++ or PERL or PHP and think that it looks so familiar that they don't need to bother learning it - they can just make arrays into objects, or into collections, or into dictionaries, and that's okay...

And that's what they do.

Nobody thought that JS was going to be a big deal.  Nobody ever imagined that.  So the inter-browser standards didn't come about until it had already become a big thing, and at that point, everybody had a different idea of what JS *was*.

Even so, Internet Explorer had the widest market share, and the most-broken and non-standard JS implementation...
That's changed, but seriously, we're just hitting a point now, where all of the new versions of browsers that matter (the big 5) support features which were outlined and standardized half a decade ago...

...that's how long it takes to turn a boat around, when you're talking about something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes
http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 1):

Classical Inheritance isn't official a language feature, but Prototypical Inheritance *is* (and has been a long time) but it's a bit unwieldy.

But it turns out, you can replicate classical inheritance with prototypes, but not the other way around. And there are plenty of libraries for just that. I like John Resig's [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) or [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) or [coffee script classes](http://coffeescript.org/#classes).

You do have constructors, but no super.

[Here's an example of how to do simple inheritance in plain old javascript.](http://jsfiddle.net/px9x4/2/)

```
// Parent "class"
var Foo = function() {
  this.barVal = 'baz';
};

// Parent instance method
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return this.barVal;
};

// Test out an instance
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar()); // 'baz'






// Child "class"
var Foo2 = function() {
  Foo.call(this); // invokes previous constructor 
};

// Assign prototypical ancestor
Foo2.prototype = new Foo();

// Child instance method
Foo2.prototype.bar = function() {
  var prevResult = Foo.prototype.bar.call(this); // invoke previous method implementation
  return prevResult + '!';
}

// New child instance method
Foo2.prototype.newMethod = function() { // new method only on child class
  return 'Some new method!'
};

// Test out an instance
var foo2 = new Foo2()
console.log(foo2.bar()) // 'baz!'
console.log(foo2.newMethod()) // 'Some new method!'​
```

But there are edge cases here too. No shame in using a tiny helper library to make this easier.

Comment: yes, it is `Foo2.prototype = new Foo();` and `Foo2.prototype.constructor = Foo2;` that is part of the `extend` function, and some people like to use an empty `F()` because then `Foo2.prototype` won't have all those extra properties and won't run for a long time if `Foo()` is complicated to run.

Comment: There a lot of ways to structure classical inheritance in JS, was sort of my point.